# What would be a RESTful design for uploading files with redirectable PUT?

Tags: rest, http

I'm looking to implement a RESTful HTTP API that allows to upload files. The server needs to decide whether a new file is desired before the client generates and uploads it. Also the upload should be redirectable to another server and `PUT` semantics for the second step would make that easier.

So far I came up with the following idea:

- The client `POST`s the textual data to `/files` based on which the server decides whether a next file is desired to be generated and uploaded
- If not, the server responds with `429 Too Many Requests` and a `Retry-After` header
- If it is, the server responds with `201 Created` and a `Location` header telling the client the URL of the file
- Then client then proceeds to generate the file and `PUT` it at the URL

Is this a valid approach?

What I'm most unsure about is whether `201 Created` is appropriate. It suggests a resource was created, but was it really, given that its empty and not valid yet? `GET`ting it would no longer give `404 Not Found` but `405 Method Not Allowed` (since only `PUT` is), so in that sense it the resource exists. If no file is `PUT` within some time, the server might expire it and give a `404 Not Found` after all, or perhaps `410 Gone`. What does the creation of a resource mean, formally?

I also considered `202 Accepted`, because processing hasn't finished, but the next processing is to be done in this case is by the client *that performed the request* rather than the server; therefore I'm not sure if that's appropriate either - it shouldn't wait for anything to become available; it should proceed to make it available on its own. Then there is `204 No Content` which might be slightly better than `201 Created`, because nothing other than the `Location` header is returned, yet it has the same conceptual problem with what it mean for a resource to exist.

Another option would be to make the API very explicit about what's happening, by renaming `/files` to something like `/file-upload-url-generator` and return a URL as actual content (with `200 OK`). However, I'm not to happy about losing uniformity and having a more complicated design (using the `Location` header seemed nice).

Comment: So just to make sure I understand, the client is going to hit an endpoint on your server to check if a file is necessary. Your server will essentially say "yes" or "no". In the event the answer is "yes", the client will need to create a file and then send it to a completely different API?

Comment: @Ellesedil The server says "no" or "yes, to this location." Whether it's a different API depends on the definition of API. It may be the same server or a different server. The server used is going to support PUT as long as the returned URL is used, and is supposed to respond to that with a plain HTTP 200 or 204 status code. There are no further semantics.

Comment: Why `GET` is not allowed on a file after it has been `PUT`?

Comment: @Opal `GET` is not allowed before `PUT` because the upload would not be finished yet. `GET` will probably not be allowed after `PUT` either, because the only purpose of the service is to receive files; not to provide them. After the first `GET`, I think the response will be `403`, `404` or `410`. Looks like we're in the same city btw. :)

Comment: The same city, what do you mean? ;)

Comment: @Opal Warsaw - according to your profile, at least :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `201` is that it must contain body - not only to be REST compliant but for compatibility with client libraries either - some client libraries throw an exception if response marked with `201` doesn't contain any data. But it the sense of a resource being valid or not `201` is good response code. Resource has been created, state doesn't matter.

`202` seems awkward a bit since as you pointed out - it indicates server side processing rather than client.

Personally I'd go for `204` for the first endpoint along with the mentioned `Location` header. The response is clear: *resource has been created, it can be found here*. The second endpoint may reply to `PUT` requests only and react appropriately.

Comment: Good to know my plans made some sense at least. And I wasn't aware of the risk of a client library panicing over that.